# Will Firebase Cloud Messaging receive messages when not running in background or foreground?

Tags: android, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an existing Google Cloud Messaging project which I am in the process of migrating to Firebase Cloud Messaging.

This GCM app delivers data/messages to my phone straight after it's turned on, i.e. the app never needs to have run. That GCM app doe this because it has a receiver declared in the manifest:

```
<receiver
                android:name="uk.co.mypackage.android.gcmjuly.GcmBroadcastReceiver"
                android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
    
                    <category android:name="uk.co.mypackage.android.gcmjuly" />
                </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

I based the FCM code on the officially suggested site's example at
[this url](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/blob/master/messaging/app/src/main/java/com/google/firebase/quickstart/fcm/MyFirebaseMessagingService.java)

My code looks like :

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "MyFirebaseMsgService";
    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        
        String item ;
        Map<String, String> data;
        data = remoteMessage.getData();

        for (String key: data.keySet()){
            item = data.get(key);
            if (key.equals("message")){
                sendNotification(item);
            }
        }
        
    }

    /**
     * Create and show a simple notification containing the received FCM message.
     *
     * @param messageBody FCM message body received.
     */
    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 /* Request code */, intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_ic_notification)
                .setContentTitle("FCM Message")
                .setContentText(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

which is very similar.

Sometimes the message can be received just after the phone is turned on, sometimes it isn't. My question is : **Is Firebase Cloud Messaging supposed to have the old GCM's receiver like capabilities ?**

i.e should it get the message even when the app hasn't been run? (Well after it's been run just once after being installed. Registering a receiver in the manifest wasn't sufficient after Honeycomb, as an anti-malware restriction)

Comment: Firebase Cloud Messaging is the next generation of Google Cloud Messaging. While the API has changed in places, the underlying product is the same. The intent you had before is nowadays auto-merged in from the Firebase aar file.

Comment: Yes it will, if you look at the merged manifest of your built application, you will see all the receivers that will allow for this type of behaviour.